# MariaDB BLOB data format in Power BI vs. Python conversion

Tags: python, powerbi, mariadb, blob, powerquery

I have a MariaDB Table containing a MEDIUMBLOB Column. There are several entries in this table corresponding to one photo each.

When querying the data to PowerBI using the MariaDB connector, I get the Data in the format "Binary"

[image]

However, when querying the same data in Python (IDE or PowerBI) the format is different:
[image]

The bigger picture is to use this code to split the image in bits as PBI has a character-limit on their data elements:

```
Source = MariaDB.Contents("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY", "ZZZZZ"),
Query1= Source{[Name="Query1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(qc_westernblot_Table,1),
//Remove unnecessary columns
RemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Top Rows",{"picture", "batchname"}),
//Creates Splitter function
SplitTextFunction = Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(30000),
//Converts table of files to list
ListInput = Table.ToRows(RemoveOtherColumns),
//Function to convert binary of photo to multiple
//text values
ConvertOneFile = (InputRow as list) =>
    let
        BinaryIn = InputRow{0},
        FileName = InputRow{1},
        BinaryText = Binary.ToText(BinaryIn, BinaryEncoding.Base64),
        SplitUpText = SplitTextFunction(BinaryText),
        AddFileName = List.Transform(SplitUpText, each {FileName,_})
    in
        AddFileName,
//Loops over all photos and calls the above function
ConvertAllFiles = List.Transform(ListInput, each ConvertOneFile(_)),
//Combines lists together
CombineLists = List.Combine(ConvertAllFiles),
//Converts results to table
ToTable = #table(type table[Name=text,Pic=text],CombineLists),
//Adds index column to output table
AddIndexColumn = Table.AddIndexColumn(ToTable, "Index", 0, 1)
```

in
AddIndexColumn

As I am a beginner on this topic, I am confident there is a straight-forward conversion missing here but I couldn't figure it out so far myself.

I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What are you planning to do with this data? PBI doesn't support binary data although you can see it in Power Query. It must be converted to something else before it can be loaded to the PBI data model.

I suspect the Python version is just the binary already converted to text. If you click the two arrows in the top right of the picture column for the PBI version, do you not get the same output?

Comment: I have a working R script that uses the binary data as an input, encodes it into Base64 and splits it. I want to perform the same task with my python query but it doesnt work. I will post the complete script in the original questions, one second please.

Comment: What happens when you click the two down arrows? Do you not get the binary converted?

Comment: I get "We didn't recognize the format of your first file (). Please filter the list of files so it contains only supported types (Text, CSV, Excel, workbooks, etc.) and try again."

Comment: I see. I'll show you the way to get one file and you can then make a function to get them all. Instead of clicking the arrows, click the word "binary" on one of the cells. This will open the png as a binary. Right click the resulting icon and choose text. You should be good to go from there.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand. I need the "x89PNG" text to be in the same format as the "Binary" import. My script works with the "Binary" import, but not with this "x89PNG" stuff. How can I convert it in python before importing or in PBI after importing so that I have it in the same "Binary" format as when I directly import it from the MariaDB database?

Comment: Ah apologies. I understand now. I'm not sure there is a way to return binary from python. Hopefully someone else knows.

Comment: In essence: I need the python query to deliver the same result, as if I would open the .png file with notepad. I hope that helps.